# Serialize class object to JSON with a custom format

Tags: c#, json

Running this program..

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace XmlConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CampaignAccountMap campaignAccountMap = new CampaignAccountMap();

            CampaignAccountMapItem campaignAccountMapItem = new CampaignAccountMapItem();
            campaignAccountMapItem.CampaignId = @"dfdf-fdfdd-fdfd-dfdfd-dfdfd";
            campaignAccountMapItem.AccountIds.Add(1245345);
            campaignAccountMapItem.AccountIds.Add(1345675);

            campaignAccountMap.Campaigns.Add(campaignAccountMapItem);

            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize<CampaignAccountMap>(campaignAccountMap);
            Console.Write(jsonString);
        }

    }
}

class CampaignAccountMap
{
    public List<CampaignAccountMapItem> Campaigns { get; set; }
    public CampaignAccountMap()
    {
        Campaigns = new List<CampaignAccountMapItem>();
    }
}

class CampaignAccountMapItem
{
    public string CampaignId { get; set; }
    public List<int> AccountIds { get; set; }
    public CampaignAccountMapItem()
    {
        AccountIds = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Outputs this JSON:

```
{
  "Campaigns": [
    {
      "CampaignId": "dfdf-fdfdd-fdfd-dfdfd-dfdfd",
      "AccountIds": [
        1245345,
        1345675
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I customize the serialized output such that it produces this output instead?

```
{
  "dfdf-fdfdd-fdfd-dfdfd-dfdfd": [
    1245345,
    1345675
  ]
}
```

Changing the name of the properties in from the class to the JSON seems doable using sterilizing annotations and such but I cant find any examples where those names are dynamic, ie I need the keys in the JSON output to be the dynamic *values* from the CampaignId property in the class.

I'm also open to doing this without using classes if I need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to just use a `Dictionary`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
foreach (var item in campaignAccountMap.Campaigns)
{
    dict[item.CampaignId] = item.AccountIds;
}

var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(dict);
Console.Write(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 2):

The desired json format can be represented by `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`.

So, you could add a `ToDictionary` method to your class, something like this:

```
class CampaignAccountMapItem
{
    public string CampaignId { get; set; }
    public List<int> AccountIds { get; set; }
    public CampaignAccountMapItem()
    {
        AccountIds = new List<int>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> ToDictionary()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, List<int>> {{ CampaignId, AccountIds }};
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
 string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(campaignAccountMapItem.ToDictionary());
 Console.Write(jsonString);
```